# How to read token value having it's accessor

Tags: hashicorp-vault

When working with Hashicorp Vault one can see token details with

`vault token lookup --accessor secret`

but is it possible to actually see this token's value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. This is for security reason. Otherwise, you will not be able to create a new (child) token and share it with someone, cause in this case `lookup` will be able to reveal your (parent) token, that is not acceptable.

In general, the output for lookup command contains `id` part. This is the token value. For `lookup` command with `--accessor` flag `id` is always `n/a` in response.